# How to postpone the execution of a piece of code in kotlin native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

We can execute a piece of code on the main thread with a specific delay on the android platform by using the `postDelayed` method of `Handler` [1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed)

Is there an equivalent way when using Kotlin native to run on iOS devices?

Comment: Have you seen this [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/multiplatform-coroutines-ios-threading/16280)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin coroutine async with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746673/kotlin-coroutine-async-with-delay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Kotlin Coroutine's [delay()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) with [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) possibly from the native-mt branch of coroutines.

You can read more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-concurrency-and-coroutines.html)